# Keychain Shop - Value in currentKeychains Variable is not Updating Properly - Java

Tags: java, methods

I am learning Java on my own and have just learned methods. I have attempted this exercise [Keychains for Sale](https://programmingbydoing.com/a/keychains2.html)

```
 // Exercise 109
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class KeychainShop {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

                int selection, currentKeychains = 0, price = 10;

                System.out.println("Welcome to the Keychain Shop!\n");

                do {
                    System.out.println("Select 1, 2, 3, or 4");
                    System.out.println("1. Add Keychains");
                    System.out.println("2. Remove Keychains");
                    System.out.println("3. View Order");
                    System.out.println("4. Checkout");

                    System.out.print("\nWhat would you like to do? ");
                    selection = keyboard.nextInt();
                    System.out.println();

                    if (selection == 1) {
                        System.out.println("You now have " + add_keychains(currentKeychains) + " keychains.");
                        System.out.println();
                    } 
                    else if (selection == 2) {
                        System.out.println("You now have " + remove_keychains(currentKeychains) + " keychains.");
                        System.out.println();
                    } 
                    else if (selection == 3) {
                        view_order(currentKeychains, price);
                        System.out.println();
                    } 
                    else if (selection == 4) {
                        checkout(currentKeychains, price);
                    }
                } while (selection != 4);
            }

            public static int add_keychains(int currentKeychains) {
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("You have " + currentKeychains + " keychains. How many would you like to add? ");
                int keychainsAdded = keyboard.nextInt();

                currentKeychains += keychainsAdded;

                return currentKeychains;
            }

            public static int remove_keychains(int currentKeychains) {
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("You have " + currentKeychains + " keychains. How many would you like to remove? ");
                int keychainsRemoved = keyboard.nextInt();

                currentKeychains -= keychainsRemoved;

                return currentKeychains;
            }

            public static void view_order(int currentKeychains, int price) {
                System.out.println("You are currently buying " + currentKeychains + " keychains.");
                System.out.println("Each keychain costs $" + price + ".");

                int totalCost = currentKeychains * price;
                System.out.println("Your current total is $" + totalCost);
            }

            public static void checkout(int currentKeychains, int price) {
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
                String name = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("You have bought " + currentKeychains + " keychains.");

                int totalCost = currentKeychains * price;
                System.out.println("Your total is $" + totalCost);
                System.out.println("Thanks for shopping with us today, " + name + ".");
            }
    }
```

My program compiles but it doesn't properly keep track of the currentKeychains (I know there's something missing, but can't figure it out).

If the user selects "1. Add Keychains" from the menu, he is asked to enter the number of keychains he wants to add. This number is added to the value stored in currentKeychains(which starts out at 0). So, if he enters 2, currentKeychains now holds 2. Then, the menu reappears and asks for the user's next selection. Now, if the user chooses to add keychains or remove keychains, the value in currentKeychains is 0 again(it should be 2). I don't understand how to fix this. There's something I'm not seeing or understanding. Also, I had to code `Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);` four times in the program, once in main, once in add_keychains(), once in remove_keychains(), and once in checkout() . Is there any way I can just type it once and allow every method to be able to use the scanner class (not sure if I worded this right)? Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`int` is a primitive type in Java, which means that it is passed by value and not by reference*. When you perform `currentKeychains += keychainsAdded` in `add_keychains`, it only modifies the *local copy* of `currentKeychains` -- it has no effect on `main`'s copy of that variable. If you want the change to be persistent, you should do one of the following:

- add `currentKeychains` as a class variable, e.g. `private static int currentKeychains`, and remove that parameter from the methods.
- use an `Integer` instead of an `int`, as this will pass a reference to an `Integer` object from which you can set the value.

The idiomatic way is the former; keeping internal state in class variables is generally the way to go.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the change persistent by keeping the parameters? What's private?

Comment: Not those parameters, no. I'll update my answer with a few alternatives. `private` is an *access modifier* which states that other classes can't access that variable -- you'll probably learn about access modifiers fairly soon.